# Find all combinations of lookup keys with at least N common values and no repeats

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I have a lookup that looks like this:

```
{ Key 1 } : { Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 }

{ Key 2 } : { Value 2, Value 3, Value 4, Value 5 }

{ Key 3 } : { Value 1, Value 3, Value 5 }

{ Key 4 } : { Value 1, Value 2, Value 3, Value 6, Value 7 }
```

I need to get all combinations of keys having at least `N` common values without repeats (i.e. if a pair of keys with common values already included in a triplet then it's considered as repeat and shouldn't be generated).

Example:

if `N == 1`, it would be `1` combination with `4` keys `{ Key 1, Key 2, Key 3, Key 4 }` because they all have `{ Value 3 }`. Any other combinations (pairs) shouldn't be generated because they are already included in the combination.

if `N == 2`, it would be `{ Key 1, Key 2, Key 4 }` (cause they have common values `2` and `3`), `{ Key 1, Key 3, Key 4 }` (cause they have common values `1` and `3`) and `{ Key 2, Key 3 }` (cause they have common values `3` and `5`). Again all other combinations (like `key1 + key3 or key3 + key4` shouldn't be generated cause these pairs are already included in triplets)

if `N == 3`, it would be `{ Key 1, Key 4 }`, because they all have `{ Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 }`

if `N == 4`, no combinations should be generated.

I'm looking for algorithm or at least some guidelines to make one.

Comment: if { Key 1 } : { Value 1, Value 2, Value 3,Value 11, Value 12, Value 13 } and  { Key 3 } : { Value 1, Value 3, Value 5,Value 11, Value 12, Value 13 } what should be the output for n==2

Comment: @AnotherGeek the result will remain the same because { Key1 } and { Key 3 } are included in a triplet { Key 1, Key 3, Key 4 } and other arrays don't contain values 11, 12 and 13

Comment: also can key have duplicated value? if this is the case can you give an example on how you want to deal with them

Answer (score 0):

The problem you posted is closely related to Frequent Itemset mining in data mining literature, also called Association Rule mining. Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#Algorithms) has more algorithms, and Ullman et al.'s book (http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch6.pdf) has a chapter as well.